# How to redirect error_page to external URL with corresponding scheme attached in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I've used the following directive in nginx config to redirect to external custom url.

```
<location block>
     :
   allow 123.123.123.123;
   deny all;
   error_page 403 http://domain.com/unauthorized.html;
     :
</location block>
```

It's working, but I would like to make redirection to corresponding `https` version if the original request is using the `https` scheme.

My nginx server block is sharing config for both port 80 and 443.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
      :
      :
}
```

I have tried the following without success:

`error_page 403 /unauthorized.html;` giving me the custom page content with original request url path in `https` (this is want I want to avoid showing).

`error_page 403 //domain.com/unauthorized.html;` giving me the default `404 Not Found` error page in `https`, same as above, revealing original request url path in the address bar.

I want: `http(s)://domain.com/admin/admin.php -> http(s)://domain.com/unauthorized.html`

How can this be done without making redundant server block declaration?

Comment: Have you tried `$scheme://domain.com/unauthorized.html`

Comment: Works perfect, solve my problem instantly.  Please post is as an answer and I'll be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$scheme` variable is set to `http` or `https` depending on the protocol used for the request.

```
allow 123.123.123.123;
deny all;
error_page 403 $scheme://domain.com/unauthorized.html;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_scheme) for details.